# Why is spacy's en_core_web_trf model returning a similarity of 0.0?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am using Spacy to do a simple NLP comparison between sentences and I am running into the following issue.

With the following code:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
score_1 = nlp('hello').similarity(nlp('hi'))

score_2 = nlp('There is a coat on the chair.').similarity(nlp('Something is on my seat.'))
```

I am being returned a score of 0.0 for both score_1 and score_2.

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall, ensure that everything is updated, and try this on a separate computer, but I am still receiving the same score of 0.0.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Both `hi` and `hello`s' `.vector_norm`s are equal to 0.

Comment: `doc.similarity` uses word vectors, but Transformers pipelines don't have word vectors. For Transformers and document similarity we recommend spacy-sentence-transformers. https://github.com/MartinoMensio/spacy-sentence-bert